# what is gem support upload file into mongomapper

Tags: mongomapper

I'm using mongo_mapper. I don't know what is gem support upload file? I've research on google, I see 'carrierwave' gem support this and i run googd with mongoid, but error with mongo_mapper:

errrors message: "undefined method 'mount_uploader' "

Thanks all

Comment: You can take a look at [joint](https://github.com/jnunemaker/joint) which will store the files in MongoDB via GridFS.  It doesn't have any built-in image resizing though.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [mm-attach-it](https://github.com/adilsonchacon/mm-attach-it), just recently created by Adilson Chacon Cavalcanti.  It supports image resizing and storing the files in GridFS.

You can also take a look at [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) which is much more mature, [here's a blog post](http://mickeyben.com/2010/10/21/handle-url-images-with-dragonfly,-mongomapper-and-rails3.html) on Dragonfly+MongoMapper (a bit old) and the official [Mongo+Dragonfly docs](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Mongo.html).

Answer (score 0):

I built a simple example of Ruby 2, Rails 4, Dragonfly and MongoMapper, available on [Github](https://github.com/JonKernPA/dragonfly)

In very little time, I had image files being stored into MongoDB's GridFS system.